# Print HTML or Word table in knitr so that whitespaces in strings are respected

Tags: r, whitespace, rstudio, knitr, xtable

Using knitr and Rstudio, I'm trying to print a dataframe to HTML or Word, so that the leading whitespaces in versicolor, will push versicolor to the right.

```
#data
library(knitr ) 
library(xtable)

df <- iris[c(1,51),c(5,1)]
df$Species  <- as.character(df$Species)
df$Species[ df$Species=="versicolor"]  <- "         versicolor"
```

Trying different combinations of kable()...

```
#table
kable(  df)
kable(  df, right = FALSE,align = c("l", "l" ) )
kable(  df, right = FALSE,align = c("r", "l" ) )
```

I get this:
[image]

...or this:
[image]

But I'm *trying* to get this:
[image]

Comment: Within kable function you will see `x = gsub("^\\s*|\\s*$", "", x)` line, I think this is why it removes all leading and trailing spaces. Maybe modify the code, and make custom kable function.

Comment: You can align columns, but not unique cells with [Pandoc's markdown](http://pandoc.org/README.html#tables).

Comment: @zx8754 Even if I don't trim the white spaces, they will not be displayed in the table anyway, since leading/trailing spaces have no special meaning in Markdown tables and will be ignored. Even if they are not ignored in Markdown, they will still be ignored in HTML by default (consecutive white spaces will be treated as one space). So I think Sharon's solution below should be the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to muck with some HTML:

```
df$Species[ df$Species=="versicolor"]  <- 
  "<code style='background:white'>         </code>versicolor"` will get you something like you want
```

or

```
df$Species[ df$Species=="versicolor"]  <- 
  "<span style='padding-left:30px'>         versicolor</span>"
```

will get you left-space-padding.

The latter might even be cleaner programmatically (inserting multiples of # in `padding-left`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding

```
df$Species <- gsub(" ", "&nbsp;", df$Species, fixed=TRUE)
```

before creating the table, that will change all your spaces before versicolor to HTML non-breaking spaces.

Comment: that will change _all_ spaces to `&nbsp;`, not just leading (needs a lookahead regex). non-breaking spaces impact line breaks at end-of-line. it won't pad.

Comment: Not sure there's anything wrong with all spaces in a species name for display in a table only having &nbsp; if it's not an interactive table where you're doing search/sort?

Answer (score 1):

Separate the leading spaces from the trailing text with one `gsub`. Then, globally replace those spaces with a second `gsub`. Lastly, combine the two parts with `paste`.

As a one-liner:

```
paste0(gsub('\\s', '&nbsp;', gsub('^(\\s*)\\S.*', '\\1', df$Species)), gsub('^\\s*(\\S.*)', '\\1', df$Species))
```

If `df$Species <- "   versicolor"`, the result is : `"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;versicolor"`

If `df$Species <- "   one two three"`, the result is : `"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;one two three"`

Or, reformatted for clarity:

```
x <- df$Species

paste0(                                 # Combine edited text
    gsub('\\s', '&nbsp;',               # Replace leading spaces
        gsub('^(\\s*)\\S.*', '\\1', x)  # Extract leading spaces
    ), 
    gsub('^\\s*(\\S.*)', '\\1', x)      # Extract trailing text
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using kableExtra package? See "Row indentation" here:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html

Basically,

```
library(kableExtra)
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
kable(dt) %>%
  kable_styling("striped", full_width = F) %>%
  add_indent(c(1, 3, 5))
```